# Desktop screen capture

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to receive a desktop screen capture from my PC using WPF (Client and server side WPF)
here is my code

```
private void ViewReceivedImage(byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {


            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
                imageSource.BeginInit();
                imageSource.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                imageSource.EndInit();

                // Assign the Source property of your image
                MyImage.Source = imageSource;
            }




            //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            //BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

            //bi.SetSource = ms;

            //MyImage.Source = bi;

            //ms.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        finally
        {
            StartReceiving();
        }
    }
```

The commented line above are for Windows phone app, I have already tested it and it works with WP8(Client Side), I have the problem only on WPF Client Side.

WPF Server Side and WP8 Client Side works
[image]
WPF Client Side not working but connection is successful 
[image]
[image]

this method sends the image

```
void StartSending()
    {
        while (!stop)

            try
            {
                System.Drawing.Image oldimage = scr.Get_Resized_Image(wToCompare, hToCompare, scr.GetDesktopBitmapBytes());


                //Thread.Sleep(1);
                System.Drawing.Image newimage = scr.Get_Resized_Image(wToCompare, hToCompare, scr.GetDesktopBitmapBytes());

                byte[] buffer = scr.GetDesktop_ResizedBytes(wToSend, hToSend);

                //float difference = scr.difference(newimage, oldimage);


                //if (difference >= 1)
                //{

                SenderSocket.Send(buffer);
                //}


            }
            catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

and this Get_Resized_Image

```
public Image Get_Resized_Image(int w, int h, byte[] image)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);

        Image bt = Image.FromStream(ms);
        try
        {
            Size sizing = new Size(w, h);
            bt = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(bt, sizing);

        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return bt;

    }
```

edited
this is the output
[image]

Comment: We cannot see how you are sending the data from the phone to the WPF Client so we cannot answer this.

Comment: As a first start: Stop throwing away the valuable exception information.

Comment: I am not sending image from phone to PC, see the send method, I am sending date from WPF server side to WPF client Side, I add the phone because I want to know if my code is right..